# IIS 7.5: Setting 'app pool user' as the anonymous user programmatically

Tags: web-config, iis-7.5

I have an web app in IIS 7.5 with its own AppPool using .net 4.

I want to use the feature of having anonymous access as the app pool identity - which is easily configured in a GUI via the inetmgr snapin.

Is there any way do this programmatically, for instance through web.config?

I've looked around and it appears that the [anonymousAuthentication](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication) element does the trick, but it does not explain how to specify the app pool user in any significant way.  I've tried setting my anon user to 'IIS APPPOOL/[AppPoolName]'  as seems to be suggested [here](http://blogs.iis.net/webtopics/archive/2009/03/13/changes-to-application-pool-identities-in-iis-7-5-beta.aspx), with no success.

Any suggestions to how this is supposed to be configured?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking a closer look at that link: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication

'If you leave this value blank (that is, username=""), Anonymous authentication uses the application pool identity to authenticate anonymous users'

Answer (score 3):

For the lazy (me)

`<system.webServer>
     <security>
         <authentication>
             <anonymousAuthentication userName="" />
         </authentication>
     </security> 
 </system.webServer>`

Comment: For the ones that are even too lazy to look up the location of the config file: `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config\applicationHost.config`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programmatically via Ansible like this:

```yaml
- name: Set 'Anonymous Authentication' to 'Application pool identity'
  community.windows.win_xml:
    path: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config\applicationHost.config
    xpath: //configuration/system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication
    attribute: userName
    fragment: ''
    type: attribute
```