# IIS Application Pool identity not working 100%

Tags: asp.net, iis

I use an ActiveX object (Rumba terminal emulation) in my dll. This ActiveX object needs to be configured for each windows user that uses it.
When I use my dll in WinForms or Windows service, it works ok, but when I use it in IIS in a ASP.NET site, then it does not work (it still works if the site is not on IIS). It does not read the settings configured for the windows user that is specified as the identity for the app pool that is assigned to the ASP.NET website, instead it reads the default settings. The identity works, but not 100%: in my DLL "Environment.UserName" gives me the username of the user specified as the identity of the app pool. I have no way to find out who the ActiveX object thinks is the current user.
So, as I see, IIS identity works, but it does not do 100% of its job, some parts are missing. How to make IIS do it's identity 100% ?

Comment: Please define "It does not work". Also mention how you configured impersonation in your web.config, and what exactly you want IIS to do. After reading your question several times, I have roughly deciphered that you want IIS to detect the identity of the user and not that of the app pool. If so, you would have to turn on impersonation.

Comment: @AmitNaidu: Impersonation is turned on: <identity impersonate="true" />. By "does not work" I mean that the ActiveX object thinks that I am another user than the one specified by the Identity of the app pool

Comment: That's good, but not enough. For impersonation, anonymous auth must also be off. A lot of information is still missing. What is the actual error message? Do you have your anonymous user set to the Application Pool Account? And it is still not clear what you actually want - do you want the code to run as each requesting user's identity OR under the identity of a specific privileged account you set as the Application Pool Identity? Impersonation needs to be on for the former and off for the latter. What does `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();` return ?

Comment: @AmitNaidu: There is no error message. The problem is that the ActiveX component does not reads the settings for the user specified by the app pool's identity. In Web.config I have: "<authentication mode="Windows" />". System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString() returns the user that is specifed as the identity of the app pool. I want the code to run under the identity of a single privileged account since this will only run on a server.

Comment: Ok but that is the ASPNET auth of your app, I am asking about IIS auth settings in [`<system.webserver>`](http://www-iis.azureedge.net/v-2016-03-08-001/images/configreference/windowsAuthentication_howto_1.png) and asking if your anon is set like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33511895/209129). If not, do so. If you want every user to run under a single privileged account, why are you using impersonation? `impersonate = "true"` means that the thread will execute under the identity of the windows user (client), not the pool identity. Is this server on a domain? What OS and IIS version?